# Laravel foreach with chance that index is different

Tags: laravel, loops, foreach, laravel-5.3

I have a loop where there are objects that the index changes. As you can see in our first object we have tv and the second has gv. The problem is, I want to loop over all the objects with the blade foreach loop that laravel provides. (This data is sent as an array, I just put it as JSON for reading)

```
[
 {
  "items" : {
    "pv" : "0",
    "tv" : "0",
    "ov" : "0"
  }
},
{
  "items" : {
    "pv" : "0",
    "gv" : "0",
    "ov" : "0"
   }
 }
]
```

This is what I could come up in terms of logic but I still get returned with Undefined index: tv

```
@foreach($products as $product)
<tr>
    <td>{{$product['items']['pv']}}</td>
    <td>
         @if( empty($product['items']['tv']) ) 
             {{$product['items']['gv']}}
         @else
             {{$product['items']['tv']}}
         @endif
    </td>
    <td>{{$product['items']['ov']}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Your code seems right for me, why don't you dump the content of $product and $products right below the foreach declaration to see what is there?

Comment: The array returned is all good. I can run the code without trying to display tv or gv by removing the center td. It displays fine.

Comment: Did you know that empty() will return true? Because empty is true for unset, null, 0, false, etc... maybe you want to use isset or array_key_exists? Also it would be good if you post the dumped array

Comment: I can't post the real array. Company data. I will try thanks!

Comment: Thanks! array_key_exist works

Answer (score 0):

```
     @if( array_key_exists('tv',$product['value']) ) 
        {{$product['value']['tv']}}
     @else
        {{$product['value']['gv']}}
     @endif
```